# get first day of last month result changes

Tags: php, date

Trying to get first day and last day of last month:

```
 $monthStart = new DateTime("first day of last month");
 $monthEnd = new DateTime("last day of last month");

 $sMonth = $monthStart->format('U');
 $eMonth = $monthEnd->format('U');

 echo $sMonth . "," . $eMonth;
```

result:

```
 1485968094,1488300894
```

do same thing 2 seconds later:

```
 1485968096,1488300896
```

do same thing 56 seconds later:

```
 1485968151,1488300951
```

Why would these values change?  I would expect the following every time:

```
 1485907200,1488240000 (for feb 2017)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set time explicitly:

```
$monthStart = (new DateTime("first day of last month"))->setTime(0,0,0);
$monthEnd = (new DateTime("last day of last month"))->setTime(23,59,59);
```

By default it  returns current time.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't specify the time compound, just the date.

You could solve this with the following snippet:

```
$monthStart = new DateTime("midnight first day of last month");
$monthEnd = new DateTime("midnight last day of last month");

$sMonth = $monthStart->format('U');
$eMonth = $monthEnd->format('U');

echo $sMonth . "," . $eMonth;
```

It defaults to the current time when there isn't a time specification.